# SQL Server Logical Device for Directories

Tags: sql-server, disk-structures

I am in need of logical backup device option for SQL Server, but not for disk files, but Windows directories. Is there anything like this available or how can I achieve that? Even from 3rd parties?

I have different folders on different machines and I need one logical name for them both, sure one on each server.

I need to create one logical directory in several servers with the same name, but their paths in actuality are different. So I can create a logical backup device with a path, which is like this `c:/myfolder/backup.bak` and all the backups initiated to this device will be appended in the same file. But I need to create it for the `c:/myfolder` directory (aka folder) without specifying the file `backup.bak`. so it will reference to a folder and not to a file, so I can create different backups in the folder with different names and separate files.

Comment: What do you mean by logical device option? Could you explain the use case a bit more?

Comment: Yes, sure @Ronaldo. I mean logical backup devices which exist for disk files, but not directories

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/define-a-logical-backup-device-for-a-disk-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: BACKUP DATABASE xxxyyy TO DISK?

Comment: What do you mean for "*Windows directories*"?...what does that have to do with SQL Server? Could you please provide a little more specifics? SQL backups have to do with SQL Server and it's database files, not a Windows directory, what is the root problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Dear @J.D., the problem is this - I need to create one logical directory in several servers with the same name, but their paths in actuality are different. So I can create a logical backup device with a path, with is like this 'c:/myfolder/backup.bak' and all the backups initiated to this device will be appended in the same file. But I need to create it for the 'c:/myfolder' directory (aka folder) without specifying the file 'backup.bak. so it will reference to a folder and not to a file, so I can create different backups in the folder with different names and separate files.

Comment: @GrantFritchey yes, only logical disk name should be instead of the real disk which points to a windows folder and not to a file. Is there an option like that avaialble?

Comment: How about a mapped drive? Requires a "real" account for the SQL Server service and that you login as that account and do the drive mapping. That would be one way to do redirection. I've used environment variables myself, in order to have the same job in an MSX environment backing up to different local folders. We used Ola Hallengrens script which back then used CmdExec with SQLCMD.EXE instead of T-SQL and we called SQLCMD using CALL to make it replace the env variable.

Comment: I see now from Ronaldo's reply that you might now have the "different folders on different machines" situation. If you don't then just use something like Ola Hallengren's scripts and Ronaldo suggests.

Comment: @TiborKaraszi yes, I have different folders on different machines and I need one logical name for them both, sure one on each server. I do not need backup scripts, the question is different, I have explained in detail in a comment above

Comment: Any reason why you’re not using [UNC paths](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/file-path-formats#unc-paths)?

Comment: Understood. Unfortunately, what you are looking for isn't in the product, so you need to think outside the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have different folders on different machines and I need one logical
> name for them both, sure one on each server.

If you have different folders on different servers and you need them to be presented with the same name you could use [mklink](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/mklink) to create a directory symbolic link.

Comment: Thanks you. This is what I needed

Answer (score 3):

In addition to mklink, using SSMS you can change the default backup location for each instance to the desired local folder, then backups to a disk location without a drive or path specified will go there.  Eg

```
backup database adventureworks2017 to disk='aw.bak'
```